# OpenCV error: Assertion Failed when calling update method on tracker object

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am iterating through frames in a video clip and running an OpenCV tracker object on each frame. The entire tracking procedure should run multiple times - each time resizing the video to a new frame width.

The procedure runs correctly the first time. Once the second iteration begins (same tracking steps as before, but resizing the frame), OpenCV throws this error:

> error: OpenCV(4.1.0)
>   /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp:1363:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) prevPyr[level * lvlStep1].size() ==
>   nextPyr[level * lvlStep2].size() in function 'calc'

The entire script is too long to post here, so here is the gist:

```
widths = [0, 1280, 640]

for width in widths:
    # call tracking function
    run_track(width)

def run_track(width):
    # Initialize the video stream and pointer to output video file
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)

    # run until no more frames
    while True:
        grabbed, frame = vs.read()

        if resize is not 0:
            frame = imutils.resize(frame, width)

        if tracker is None:
            tracker = tracker_inst

            tracker.init(frame, tuple(gt_bb))

        if tracker is not None:
            tracking, trk_bb = tracker.update(frame)

            # do custom tracking procedure, save frames, etc
```

Regardless of what the first value in `widths` is, it runs fine the first time. Once the iteration begins for the second value in `widths`, the error is thrown. Is it a referencing issue? Even if I add `frame = None` at the beginning of the function declaration, the error is thrown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two main possibilities for your case

**1)** These kind of problems mostly depend on the `opencv-python-contrib` module. If you dont the `contrib` part, tracker objects are not included in the `opencv-python` one.

**2)** If you have `opencv-python-contrib` you are probably experiencing a kind of version mismatch with the main functions and `contrib` functions.

My suggestion is to check these are valid on your system or not.